# angularJS Filter and $http

Tags: angularjs

im new at angularJs and i had this problem.
y is the result that the filter will show and x is the result that i need to show. but y keeps showing an $$state Json array. please help me with this.

```
var filter = function(key,locale){
locale="fr";
var y=$http.get('https://...').then(function(res){
    var dataLocale=res.data[locale];
    var x=dataLocale[key];
    console.log(x);
    //this shows what i want
    return x;
});
console.log(y);
//this doesn' show what i want
return y;
```

}

Comment: That's because of the execution of Promise.  Promises execute asynchronously.  The `console.log(y)` would probably execute before the promise is resolved.

Comment: Thanks  @sid but how can i fix it ?

Comment: A filter is used to format data. Not to execute http requests. That code has nothing to do in a filter.

Comment: the filter goal is to translate the key to an other language. i get the translation from the http request.

Comment: Making an http request for each key, and redoing it every time you get back to the template to re-fetch the translation again and again is a terrible idea. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use angular-translate. I also really wonder why you're starting (I guess) a new project with AngularJS, which is now EOLed.

Comment: It's not me who started the project. im just demanded to complete it without using any external module.

Comment: Load the JSON containing the translations once and for all, from a service called at initialization time. Use these loaded translations in your filter. But really, you need to understand the concept of asynchrony when using JavaScript and AngularJS. Read https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/